# transferring local files to Databricks DBFS system using CLI in python code not working

Tags: python, file, command-line-interface, databricks, transfer

Here is the issue: when I run the stand alone command to transfer file from on-prem location to DBFS, it works

```
databricks fs cp /mnt/farm/DNAlab/WGL/Samples/Data\ Analysis/Emedgene/HPO/2213305.HPO.txt dbfs:/FileStore/LiveDataUpload/WES_HPO_Dec16/
```

but when I run it inside my python code, it fails.

```
 my_cmd = "databricks fs cp "+row_file+" "+upload_dir
                run_args = {"shell":True, "check":True, "capture_output":True}
                subprocess.run(my_cmd, **run_args)
```

please help... why ?

Answer (score 0):

If we avoid using `shell=True` we'll have an easier time working with filenames that contain spaces.

Something like this should work:

```py
src = "/mnt/farm/DNAlab/WGL/Samples/Data Analysis/Emedgene/HPO/2213305.HPO.txt"
target = "dbfs:/FileStore/LiveDataUpload/WES_HPO_Dec16/"

subprocess.run(["databricks", "fs", "cp", src, target], capture_output=True, check=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but filename is not an issue here

Comment: Then update your question to show the value of `row_file`, the value of `upload_dir`, and the exact error message you're seeing. There's not a lot of information to work with, and `row_file+upload_dir` contains the filename as you've shown in your shell command, then the filename *is* the problem.

Comment: ok, so I figured the source of the problem... Code works but when I submit the code through crontab, it fails. and error is:    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'databricks fs cp /mnt/farm/DNAlab/WGL/Samples/Data\ Analysis/Emedgene/HPO/2303946.HPO.txt dbfs:/FileStore/LiveDataUpload/WES_HPO_Test/' returned non-zero exit status 127.